# Cannot read GET request

Tags: node.js, express, get

I have a problem, I am trying to read GET request which goes to this web server, but it doesn't read it! It should output it after 10 seconds when user request came. Could anybody help me, please?
The program algorithm is to handle the GET request and output it in Node.JS console.

```
    var express        =        require("express");
    var app            =        express();
    var bssid;
    app.get('handle',function(request,response){
        bssid=request.bssid;
        setTimeout(() => { console.log(`BSSID: ${bssid}`)}, 10000);
    });



    const port = 9090


    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server running at http://${port}/`);

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `query` property of the request object when trying to read the input. If you want to read GET parameters (called the query string) from the request URL, you have to use the `request.query` object, e.g. `request.query.bssid`. See related Express [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).

Example:

```
app.get('handle', function (request, response) {
  bssid = request.query.bssid;
  setTimeout(() => { console.log(`BSSID: ${bssid}`)}, 10000);
});
```

This, when called as `localhost:3000/handle?bssid=1234`, will log `1234` to the server console.

Comment: It doesn't output to console anything about BSSID. My code:               var express        =        require("express");
var app            =        express();
var bssid;

app.get('handle', function (request, response) {
  bssid = request.query.bssid;
  setTimeout(() => { console.log(`BSSID: ${bssid}`)}, 10000);
  //return response.send('Done'); //return response
});

const port = 3002

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running!`);
 });

Comment: I have "Cannot GET /handle" on output in the browser. Maybe because of this, it doesn't work?

Comment: Oh, I found how to fix it, I have just changed from handle to / and strange, but on main it works)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something in your `response`

Try something like this:

```
app.get('handle',function(request,response){
    bssid=request.bssid;
    setTimeout(() => { 
        console.log(`BSSID: ${bssid}`);
        return response.send('Done'); //return response
        }, 10000);
    });
```